# Debugging QML with Qt creator

Tags: qt, debugging, qml

I have a Qt (5.8.0) project using QML files. I would like to set breakpoints in the QML file using Qt creator (4.2.1) so I can follow the flow. However I cannot get it to work. I have enabled "Enable QML debugging and profiling" in the qmake build step and "Enable C++" and "Enable QML" in the run step.

The breakpoints in the C++ code are hit, but the QML are ignored. When starting I get the following message:

```
QDeclarativeDebugServer: Ignoring 
\"-qmljsdebugger=port:42715,block,services:DebugMessages,QmlDebugger,V8Debugger,QmlInspector\". 
Debugging has not been enabled.
```

When I try to debug QML files in demo projects like "Calendar" with the same kit it does work and breakpoints are hit.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found myself here and then figured out my problem: QML debugging works by a collaboration between the `QApplication` and the debugger, with the `-qmljsdebugger` flag, which magically gets consumed by the `QApplication` c'tor. I had made a "dummy" `QAppliation` in order to parse the command-line args before launching my app. As a result, the first `QApplication` consumed the arg, and so the "real" `QApplication` never saw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to make it work. Looks like I am using the combination of Qt5, while using the Declarative package and Qt Quick 1.1. When I removed the Declarative package and instead use the qml and quick packages (Qt+=qml quick) and updated my software to use Qt Quick 2.2, the breakpoints were hit (also using the #include  as suggested by the answer of Jens)

Answer (score 4):

Did you enable the QML Debugger in your code?
I remember putting something like this into my code:

For Qt4:

```
#include <QtDeclarative/qdeclarativedebug.h>
QDeclarativeDebuggingEnabler qmldbg;
```

or in case of Qt5:

```
#include <QQmlDebuggingEnabler>
QQmlDebuggingEnabler enabler;
```

Also QML debugging needs to be activated in the Execution Settings:
[image]

Comment: That does seem to fix the "QDeclarativeDebugServer ignoring" message. Now it says "Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!" However the breakpoints are still not being hit in the QML.

Comment: Can you see a message like "QDeclarativeDebugServer: Waiting for connection on port 3768..." on the console?

Comment: When I use your "Qt4" solution I do get the message: "Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!
QDeclarativeDebugServer: Waiting for connection on port 40393...
QDeclarativeDebugServer: Connection established"

Comment: However when I try the Qt5 solution (and adding Qt+=quick to my project) I get some confusing messages: "QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
"QDeclarativeDebugServer: Ignoring \"-qmljsdebugger=port:36014,block,services:DebugMessages,QmlDebugger,V8Debugger,QmlInspector\". Debugging has not been enabled.""

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove a package from my .pro file:

```
#CONFIG += qtquickcompiler
```

With this line commented out and confirming my project's build steps: "Enable QML debugging and profiling" was checked, the breakpoints worked.